# How to change docked icons on android for a custom rom?

Tags: android, icons, apk, dock, rom

Is their anyway to have your apk's show where all the docked icons are showing on Android? Other then manually going thru the phone and dragging the app(familiar with this). Basically if I wanted to build a custom rom and I wanted an apk to show on the docked icons, how would I go about making that happen.